# Char* returns garbage value after malloc?

Tags: c, char, malloc

this function *ideally* takes a string and returns the letters past the first word (or "command") based on an integer. I.e:

```
input: "write 1234"      //valLen = 4  and  inputStr = "write 1234"
output: "1234"
```

"Extractor Function":

```
char* ExtractValue(unsigned int *valLen, char *inputStr)
{
int sizeToAllocate = strlen(inputStr) - (strlen(inputStr) - *valLen) + 1;
unsigned int i = 0;
int count = 0;

/* memory aloc */
printf("Assigning %d bits of space...\n", sizeToAllocate);
char *outStr = (char*)malloc(sizeToAllocate);
if (!outStr)
{
    perror("Error allocating memory");
    abort();
}

/*sets final string to value entered*/
for (i = 0; i < strlen(inputStr); i++)
{
    if (strlen(inputStr) - i <= *valLen)
    {
        outStr[count] = inputStr[i];
        count++;
    }
}

return outStr;
}
```

And it works for the most part; however, the return string is always proceeded by garbage values for some reason. It seems as if `malloc()` initializes `outstr` to already used memory (with a bunch of gibberish in it) and the for loop adds characters to the beginning of it. An example would be:

```
input: "write 1234"
output: "1234══²²²²¼"
```

Why would it do that? Any explanations greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your main problem is probably that you don't null-terminate your output, but as a FYI, `strlen(inputStr) - (strlen(inputStr) - *valLen) + 1` simplifies to just `*valLen + 1` - is that what you meant?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize memory - it just allocates it. The values at the pointer could be anything. Use `calloc` to clear the memory.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`, there's no need to in C and doing so can mask more serious issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question already! `malloc` just allocates memory and doesn't bother clearing out whatever was there before. You can use `calloc` to get a block of memory that's been zeroed out, or modify your loop to add a null character at the end of the string.

```
/*sets final string to value entered*/
for (i = 0; i < strlen(inputStr); i++)
{
    if (strlen(inputStr) - i <= *valLen)
    {
        outStr[count] = inputStr[i];
        count++;
    }
}

/* null terminate the string */
outStr[count++] = "\0";
```

Comment: I think `count` would have already been incremented. Use `outStr[count] = "\0";` instead.

Comment: @nalyd88 I'm just incrementing it again in case they want to add more code after this. That way, count will always point to the next character position in the string (which I guess is already terminated, so it's not *that* helpful.

Comment: Gotch ya. However, considering that the OP didn't know how `malloc` works, you may want to explain post-incrementing... lol

Comment: `calloc` was what I was looking for! A bit silly that I couldn't find this elsewhere... A bought a book about C and it hasn't arrived yet so I'm partly just learning from this forum :p